# Struggling to implement a timer

Tags: haskell

I would like to implement a simple timer that I can

1. exit at any time and get result
2. run any number of times.

I come up with `timer1` implementation. It satisfies (2) and almost satisfies (1) since it has to wait until `threadDelay` finishes. Any pointer would be appreciated.

ps. The another implementation with `catch` exception handling I have tried exits immediately but cannot exit via SIGINT twice or else the program will be terminated.

```hs
timer1 :: MVar () -> Int -> IO Int
timer1 v sec = do
  putStrLn (show sec)
  threadDelay 1000000
  tryTakeMVar v >>= \case
    Just _ -> return sec
    Nothing -> exitCond
  where
    exitCond = if sec > 0 then timer1 v (sec - 1) else return 0

main :: IO ()
main = do
  v <- newEmptyMVar
  installHandler sigINT (CatchOnce $ putMVar v ()) Nothing
  res <- timer1 v 5
  putStrLn $ "timer1: " ++ show res

  v <- newEmptyMVar
  installHandler sigINT (CatchOnce $ putMVar v ()) Nothing
  res <- timer1 v 5
  putStrLn $ "timer1: " ++ show res
```

Comment: As for me, your problem is not clear. What you want to do with timer? Measure duration of some action? Limiting duration of some action? Or both things? Or some else?

Comment: @freestyle I want to implement a pausable timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend spawning a thread that waits the right amount of time and then fills the MVar:

```
import Data.Time.Clock

timer1 :: MVar () -> Int -> IO Int
timer1 m sec = do
    before <- getCurrentTime
    forkIO (threadDelay (sec*1000000) >> putMVar m ())
    takeMVar m
    after <- getCurrentTime
    return (sec - floor (diffUTCTime after before))
```

Whichever of the forked `threadDelay` or the signal handler that fires first will wake up `timer1`'s `takeMVar`.

Your `main` can remain unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I put together quickly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import Control.Concurrent
import System.Posix
import Data.IORef

timer1 :: MVar () -> IORef Int -> Int -> IO ()
timer1 v t sec = do
  writeIORef t sec
  putStrLn (show sec)
  threadDelay 1000000
  if sec > 0
     then timer1 v t (sec - 1)
     else putMVar v ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
  v <- newEmptyMVar
  t <- newIORef 5
  installHandler sigINT (CatchOnce $ putMVar v ()) Nothing
  tid <- forkIO $ timer1 v t 5
  takeMVar v         -- wait for timer or user interrupt
  killThread tid     -- stop the timer
  res <- readIORef t -- read the current time
  putStrLn $ "timer1: " ++ show res
  
  v <- newEmptyMVar
  t <- newIORef 5
  installHandler sigINT (CatchOnce $ putMVar v ()) Nothing
  tid <- forkIO $ timer1 v t 5
  takeMVar v
  killThread tid
  res <- readIORef t
  putStrLn $ "timer1: " ++ show res
```

The main idea is to use the `MVar` both for the signal and for the timer end.
Then you can run the timer in a separate thread and wait for the `MVar` to be filled in the main thread. That means you do need to keep track of the current time in some other way, I chose to use an `IORef` for that.